# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

I have deployed OpenCRX CRM and tried to build it but it is throwing following exception,

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:66)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:507)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1323)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2750)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:828)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:757)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:133)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1211)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:551)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:766)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createRegistry(MBeanUtils.java:1064)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.(MBeanUtils.java:93)
>       ... 28 more

Just would like to know when such a exception is thrown and what are possibilities that occurred and what would be the solution? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error. Was starting Tomcat through Eclipse Run configuration.
What I found out is that all jars from Tomcat /lib folder were in classpath. When remove them from there, the problem has gone.
So try to find are those in your classpath, and remove them.